Jmeter: how to substitude the dynamical random values in request-2 for multiple iterations running request-1 only one time
Requirement: Capturing dynamical values from Request-1 and occurrence count is let say 5.i need to substitute the random values for multiple iteration with request-2 without running the request-1 for multiple times.
Could you please help me to fulfill the requirement.
i did like below
Http request-1
Postprocessor(captured all the occurances)
Http request-2 (This need to execute multiple times with only one time of http request-1)
Need solution or approach to fulfill the requirment

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Welcome. Take the [tour] and then see how to [ask].

Use a suitable Post-Processor for extracting the values from the "Http request-1"
It will create the following JMeter Variables
var_1=foo
var_2=bar
var_3=baz
xxx
var_matchNr=the number of matches 

Then you will be able to run "Http request-2" as many times as there are matches from the Post-Processor using i.e. ForEach Controller
